# Is it possible to call a method using a variable?

Tags: java

In PHP (for example), you can use this way to call a function using a variable like this:

```
$funcname = "print";
$funcname("Whatever..."); // Same as: print("Whatever...");
```

What is the way used in Java?

Comment: Good God, why would you want to?

Comment: I want to create a function that loops over an array, and passing each of the elements of the array trough a specific function.
Like this: ArrayWalk("ToLower", array)

Comment: Java got no closures, so yes, you must either use reflection (which the Java community considers bad practice) or anonymous inner classes (which everyone except the Java community consider bad practice).

Comment: Or you could use an Interface, like God and Gosling intended.

Comment: @Zippo not 100% certain what you are trying to do there, but I *really* think that if you explained your *actual* goal in another post, it would be obvious that there is a non-reflective way to do it.

Comment: @zippo agree with david, you should ask your actual goal in another question

Comment: clearly, many of you are not understand functional programming works or how awesome it is...

Comment: Understanding the awesome functional programming wont help you (or me or anyone else) either to overcome Java's awkward limitations.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use

```
Class<?> klass = object.getClass();
Method method = klass.getMethod("name", String.class); // parameter types, if any
method.invoke(object, "whatever"); // parameters, if any
```

plus boilerplate code to catch 5 different exception (they promised to introduce a common supertype in Java 7).

Comment: blurk!  I just threw up on my shoes.

Answer (score 17):

Please keep in mind that reflection of this kind is not typical in Java the way it is in more functionally-oriented languages like Ruby or even (wait for it) C#. There's nothing wrong with the technique *per se*, but you do lose compiler protection which may result in difficult-to-find bugs or confusing code for other devs who don't anticipate these kinds of paths. I'm not one that thinks all reflection in Java is considered harmful, but it's definitely not mainstream practice. Use with caution.

Perhaps a better and more Java-friendly solution would be to use a [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). Create an array of functional-like objects with an "execute" method that performs the various operations you want. Use an Interface to abstract.

```
public interface Command {
    public void execute();
}

public class Foo implements Command{
    public void execute() {
        // do some stuff 
    }
}
```

You can implement Command in a concrete class or anonymous inner class and iterate over an array of Commands:

```
List<Command> commandArray = new <Command>ArrayList();
commandArray.add(new Foo());
commandArray.add(new Command(){
    public void execute() {
        // some more stuff;
    }
});

for (Command command : commandArray){
    command.execute();
}
```

EDIT: per Adrian's comment, here's a way to call a method/command from a variable iterating over an array of values:

```
public interface StringCommand {
    public void execute(String value);
}

stringCommand = new StringCommand(){
    public void execute(String value){
        System.out.println(value.toLowerCase());
    }
}

String[] stringAry = {"foo", "fu", "Whatever..."};

for(String value : stringAry){
    stringCommand.execute(value);
}
```

Would be similar in Ruby to:

```
string_command = lambda {|value| puts value.downcase }
["foo", "fu", "Whatever..."].each { |value| string_command.call(value)}
```

Comment: -1 OP said in comment that OP wants to apply to same function to all elements in an array, ie OP wants the equivalent of Ruby's each. Can you change your example to address that?

Answer (score 7):

Although you *can* do this with reflection as many have indicated, for the use case you mention in your comment responding to the comment asking "why?", I'd use an interface instead.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. Use [Method.invoke](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29). Also there is some examples [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html)

Answer (score 2):

[Java Reflection API](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/) can provide this functionality. (Not exactly as PHP does it, thou)

Answer (score 1):

You could use reflection, but if you want to have a method that prints something, and you want to change that behavior later, just write a method and call that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection as others have suggested. Syntactically it is quite different from what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Next version of JDK - JDK7 would probably have closures support.
If you don't want to wait for official release in Fall 2011 you can try betta versions already. google for Java/JDK 7.